# Convert application under win16 with a driver to win32

Tags: c++, windows, serial-communication

In general, what needs to be done to convert a 16 bit Windows program to Win32? The application is used to be serial communication with a driver. I have known how to use the DLL file of the driver. Then what is the next step? I hope to hear some useful information, not copied from other website.

The code in question is C++

Thanks

Comment: those involve alot of calculating? replace your ints to shorts?

Answer (score 1):

If the app is using a driver to access a serial port, then drop the driver altogether.  In Win32, you can use the standard Win32 API `CreateFile()`, `ReadFile()`, and `WriteFile()` functions to read/write data over a serial port, and various `SetComm...()` functions (`SetCommState()`, `SetCommTimeouts()`, `SetCommMask()`, etc) to configure the port settings.  Refer to MSDN for more details:

[Serial Communications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff802693.aspx)